# how to use observed livedata outside of observe block

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I want to put the observed LiveData in a list and you that list elsewhere in the code. Like this:

```
        var listCategory = listOf<Category>()

        categoryViewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            listCategory = it
        }
        
        //do something with listCategory
```

CategoryViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class CategoryViewModel @Inject constructor(private val categoryDao: CategoryDao) :ViewModel() {
    private val categoryFlow = categoryDao.getCategoryFlow()
    val categories = categoryFlow.asLiveData()

    fun addCategory(name:String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            categoryDao.insert(Category(name = name))
        }
    }
}
```

CategoryDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(category: Category)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(category: Category)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(category: Category)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category_table")
    fun getCategoryFlow(): Flow<List<Category>>
}
```

But listCategory is always empty. How can I use observed data outside the observation block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `listCategory` has `List<Category>` type, which is immutable. This is also declared as `val`, which means that you cannot legally use `listCategory = something`
To allow mutations and adding, you should create it as a mutable list like this

```
val listCategory = mutableListOf<Category>()
```

And then, in observe block you can

```
categoryViewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    listCategory.addAll(it)
}
```

Moreover I suggest to perform manipulations with livedata and its' dependent components in `observe` block, to make sure, that livedata changes will be processed.

Comment: even though  i made the list mutable, it's still empty outside

Comment: @Jane you need to make sure that your livedata gets updated, can you edit your question and post the code, where you initialize your livedata?

Comment: @Jane do you call `addCategory` somewhere?

Comment: yeah i do call it. when I take the log of the list that the observation returns, it is not empty. So I know that the observation gets the data. but somehow the listCategory remains empty

Comment: weirdly, when I take the log of the listCategory inside the observation block, it contains the elements. but when I look at the log outside of the block, it becomes empty.

Comment: Jane, do you use observe block inside a composable function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249762/discussion-between-steyrix-and-jane).

Comment: putting all the list-related operations in the observation block solved the problem. Thanks @Steyrix